# JMeter update user defined variable at run time

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to update the user defined variable set at a test plan level from a thread group. This is my scenario:
Test plan> user defined variable (variable name/value: fBurst=0)
Test plan> Threadgroup1 > Once only controller> JSR223 test plan (inside the test plan I have the following code)

```
log.info("fBurst user defined value : " + ${fBurst})
vars.put("fBurst", Integer.toString(111))
log.info("fBurst user defined value vars.put' : " + ${fBurst})
props.put("fBurst", 222)
log.info("fBurst user defined value props.put' : " + ${fBurst})
```

[image: JSR223]

[image: UDV]

What I am trying to do here is to update the fBurst user defined value from inside the once only controller sampler and so far not been able to do it using the vars.put or props.put. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JSR223 Sampler documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler):

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:
>
> - Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
> - Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
>
> When using this feature, **ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement**. Instead use script parameters.

So replace `${fBurst}` with `vars.get('fBurst")` or `props.get('fBurst')` correspondingly and it should start working as expected

More information: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)